# Basic character controller. (2d game)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controller

I'm struggling for about 5-6 hours to find a way to controll my character in c#. I just want to make it as simple as posible. (press W - it goes up, release the W key, it stops) And absolutly nothing I could find on google helps. Even it's a reaaally long code, which i don't understand because I just started learning, even it's not what I want. For example, that's like the most viewed tutorial, but it doesn't work for my 'game'. It might work for a character that's flaoting/flying, but not for a basic one.

```
private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
public float speed = 10f;

void Start()
{
    rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector2 movement = new Vector2(moveHorizontal, moveVertical);
    rb2d.AddForce(movement * speed);
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Unity. Even experienced programmers have a learning curve when moving from line of business apps to game dev. I think [this tutorial will help you](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/2d-ufo-tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either rewrite

```
rb2d.AddForce(movement * speed);
```

to

```
rb2d.AddForce(movement * speed, ForceMode2D.Force);
```

or replace it entirely with

```
rb2d.velocity = movement * speed;
```